# uniform distribution with density function?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, estimation, computational-statistics, distributions

If $0.3,0.2,0.8,0.3,0.4$‌ are found from one random instance with uniform distribution with following density function, We need to find $\theta $ estimate with Method of moments. how should we do this?‌

$f_\theta = \frac {1}{\theta}, 0<x< \theta $

Any hint or idea?

Comment: You can solve $\bar{x} = E(X)$ for $\theta$.

Comment: As @ocram hints, doubling the mean is one way to go here. Why insist on the method of moments? Is this an exercise? There are many approaches to this famous problem.

Comment: @NickCox Doubling the mean _is_ Method of Moments here.

Comment: @Alecos Quite so; I do understand that, but if you found my comment unclear, please consider my second sentence to mean "Why insist on using this method of moments?"

Comment: Please don't post homework-style questions without marking with the `self-study` tag (and following the guidelines at the [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)).

Comment: @NickCox Now that is interesting! I hope you will have the time to post something more elaborate on the matter.

Comment: There was a treatment in E.T. Jaynes' book, _Probability Theory: The Logic of Science_ Cambridge U.P. 2003 He (rather characteristically) ignores previous work in different styles, e.g. Leo A. Goodman. Serial number analysis. _Journal, American Statistical Association_ 47: 622-634, 1952.

Comment: @NickCox, this is extracted from this book ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. I just gave two references; no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pdf of the uniform distribution $U[0,\theta]$ is

$$
f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   \dfrac{1}{\theta}, &  0\leq x \leq \theta \\
   0,       & \mathrm{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$

Hence the first population moment is

$$
\mu_{1} = \mathrm{E}(X)=\int_{0}^{\theta}\frac{x}{\theta}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\theta}{2}
$$

The first sample moment is

$$
\hat{\mu}_{1} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i} = \bar{X}
$$

Now we equate the sample moment to the population moment and solve for $\theta$:
$$
\hat{\mu}_{1} = \frac{\theta}{2}   \Longrightarrow \hat{\theta} = 2\times\hat{\mu}_{1} = 2\times \bar{X}
$$
So as @AlecosPapadopoulos said in the comments: Doubling the sample mean is the Method of Moments estimator for $\theta$.

More information about Method of Moments estimation and the uniform distribution can be found in [this pdf document.](http://www.isical.ac.in/~arnabc/sm2/mme.pdf)

Comment: I think without the specific numerical result this is actually a very good answer.

Comment: @Glen_b Your first comment was spot-on, I think. I apologize for violating the policy, I meant no harm. In hindsight, it is obvious that this is a homework question but I was in a hurry when I wrote the answer and somehow I missed it. I deleted the numerical result now. Sorry again.

Comment: It looks fine now.